# Is it possible to have at the same time positive slope and negative correlation coefficient?

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot, ggpubr

I plot some variables using ggscatter and get the following plot as a result

[image: correlation plot using spearman]

It happens with several pairs of variables and I am wondering if I do something completely wrong or I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check with `cor(x, y, method = "spearman")`. A priori it is possible for the Spearman correlation (but not for the Pearson correlation).

Comment: Lacking data or any reproducibility, this seems to be about the *theory* and not practical application. As such, I'm voting to move it to [stats.se] where it makes more sense (to me).